# Why the output of 5u and -5u are different?

Tags: c++

```
cout<<-5u
```

It give output: 65531 why?

```
cout<<5u
```

It just give output 5 
Then why the outputs are different why -5u cant give -5 output.

Comment: `u` is unsigned, so you just tried to print a negative number to a unsigned, this wrapped over to the maximum range for a unsigned int, 0-65531

Comment: Suppose that `unsigned` is 1 byte (for comodity; it's common to see them as 2 or 4 bytes). `5u` means `b00000101`, and because `-1u` is `b11111111` in binary, you just subtract 4 from it, so `-5u` is `b11111011`, which as an `int`, it is `251`. Scale this answer to the your `unsigned` size, and you'll get your answer.

Comment: The outputs are different because the values are different.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ unsigned integers underflow and overflow in a [well defined way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) (as apposed to signed integers). In particular, arithmetic operations are `mod 2^n` where `n` is the number of bits representing the `unsigned int`. `-5u` is equivalent to `0u - 5u` which is equal to `(0u - 1u) - 4u`. `0u - 1u` gives [`UINT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits)(or `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`), which is `65535`. So you have `-5u = 65535 - 4 = 65531`.

Comment: To be pedantic: There is no overflow or underflow in unsigned integer arithmetic. Unsigned integers implement arithmetic in Z mod 2^NumBits and thus can represent any integer by choosing the representative of its equivalence class that lies in [0, 2^NumBits).

Comment: Plzz tell me one thing how 0u-1u gives UINT_MAX

Comment: @user7919320 "arithmetic operations are `mod 2^n` where `n` is the number of bits representing the `unsigned int`".

Comment: Daniel tell me how 0u-1u give. UINT_MAX

Comment: @user7919320 I have. Twice.